# Изменение manyToMany объекта в django

Tags: python, django

Имеется модель Task в которой есть сущность sotry.

При создании задачи указываются сотрудники, за которыми эта задача заключается. Но бывают случаи, когда к созданной задаче необходимо добавить еще сотрудников. Это можно сделать путем редактирования существующей задачи. Заполняя соответствующую форму, подставляя instance=task, я могу добавлять и убирать сотрудников. При таком раскладе, в моей форме выводится список всех сотрудников.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при редактировании задачи, в поле SelectMultiple у меня выводились не все сотрудники, а только те, которые не задействованы в задаче?

```
*models.py*

class Task(models.Model):
    sotry = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, verbose_name='Сотрудники', blank=True)

class Employee(models.Model):
    sur_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Имя')
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Отчество')


*forms.py*

class AddEmpTask(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('sotry',)
        widgets = {
            'sotry': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }


*views.py*

def add_emptask(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddEmpTask(request.POST, instance=task)
        if form.is_valid():
             t = form.save(commit=False)
             form.save_m2m()
             t = form.save()
            return redirect('task_url', pk)
    else:
        form = AddEmpTask(instance=task)
    return render(request, 'rootApp/employees/add_emptask.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в методе инит формы можете переопределить queryset для нужного поля

```
class AddEmpTask(forms.ModelForm):
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["sotry"].queryset = Employee.objects.exclude(pk__in=[employee.pk for employee in self.instance.sotry.all()]
...
```

Но если Вы хотите показывать только новых сотрудников(тех, что не привязаны к задаче), то при сохранении Вы должны будете добавить тех, кто уже есть у задачи, иначе новый набор сотрудников заменит старый. Это можно сделать либо в методе `save`, либо в методе `clean`, добавив в `self.cleaned_data["sotry"]`  тех сотрудников, что были выбраны раньше и текущий выбор